# Cisco 2148T FEX Port Capabilities Error

Tags: cisco-nexus-2000

*Does a Cisco 2148T FEX not support 100 Mb interface speed?*

When trying to manually configure a host port to run at 100/full on a 2148 FEX I receive an error that states:

**ERROR:  Configuration does not match the port capability**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it does not.  The 2148 FEX has 48 1000Base-T host interfaces.  You can confirm this by checking the interface capabilities with the following command (this taken from a 2248 which does support 100Base-TX):

```
Nexus# show interface ethernet 102/1/3 capabilities
Ethernet102/1/3
  Model:                 N2K-C2248TP-1GE
  Type (Non SFP):        --
  Speed:                 100,1000,auto
  Duplex:                full
  Trunk encap. type:     802.1Q
  Channel:               no
  Broadcast suppression: no
  Flowcontrol:           rx-(off/on),tx-(off/on)
  Rate mode:             none
  QOS scheduling:        rx-(6q1t),tx-(1p6q0t)
  CoS rewrite:           no
  ToS rewrite:           no
  SPAN:                  yes
  UDLD:                  no
  Link Debounce:         yes
  Link Debounce Time:    yes
  MDIX:                  no
  Pvlan Trunk capable:   yes
  TDR capable:           no
  FabricPath capable:    no
  Port mode:             Switched
  FEX Fabric:            no
```